# Unable to boot into USB after enrolling MOK on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Tags: boot, usb

I was prompted to enroll MOK when I updated VirtualBox on my Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS. Since then I have not been able to boot into a live medium such as a USB. I have a triple boot Lenovo G50-80 laptop (Windows+Ubuntu+Manjaro).

I have looked around for the solution and it appears that there are a number of similar queries. However, the solutions do not work out for me. I do not have TPM in my BIOS settings. Disabling secure boot has not worked for me. My HDD and SSD show up but not the bootable USB. I can boot from the USB on VirtualBox and Qemu but not on my laptop.

What options do I have to restore my system back to the state where I can boot from a USB? I would need to if I have to recover data. I have one MOK enrolled.

I do not know how enrolling MOKs worked. Will uninstalling `mokutil` serve the purpose? Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Disabling secure boot has not worked for me* ??? Disabling Secure Boot *automatically* disables the need for MOK. And nothing Secure Boot or MOK related have anything to do with booting USB media. The question reads as a complete confusing disaster. The mention of SB implies UEFI mode. Is your USB able to boot in UEFI mode? Typically Virtualbox works in Legacy/ "BIOS" mode.

Comment: I agree with you that what I asked is confusing. In fact, that was the reason for asking. Disabling SB should have worked, I know. I apologize for any confusion caused and thanks for patiently reading through it. As of now, I am able to boot into the same USB, only occasionally. I have checked with other bootable USBs also - the same problem of not being detected as a bootable device. I request someone who can figure it out, should I then mark it off as a hardware issue?